# hanging a chin-up bar from floor joists in basement

Tags: joists

My question is similar to a question above about chin  up bar. The broad question simply is it safe from the standpoint of structural integrity to put nails or screws directly into floor joists, period.  The user's safety I am accouonting for by distributing the load (and if it fails,  they will fall about 6" and land on their feet...)

Comment: What question "above"? Any off-page resource should be properly referenced with a descriptive link. Please revise to do that and to provide enough detail in _this_ question so we can answer. We don't even know what kind of joists you have.

Answer (score 1):

Nails and screws into floor joists are not a problem. There *may* be a problem with weight, but personally I wouldn't be concerned with a chin-up bar and the weight of one person.

Where there are some critical code rules are with respect to holes and notches - both are limited as to how large they can be and where they can be located.